# Override predefined predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have written the following predicate append/3 to implement the combination of two lists:

```
append([L|Ls],R,[L|Result]):-append(Ls,R,Result).
append([],X,X).
```

It gives a correct output, yet when I trace the execution flow of the code, here is what I get:

```
1 ?- edit.
true.

2 ?- make.
% //dougal/cs0u$/cyw03u/desktop/lab3 compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
true.

3 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 3 ?- append([a,b,c],[d,e],X).
   Call: (6) append([a, b, c], [d, e], _G554) ? creep
   Call: (7) lists:append([b, c], [d, e], _G636) ? creep
   Exit: (7) lists:append([b, c], [d, e], [b, c, d, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) append([a, b, c], [d, e], [a, b, c, d, e]) ? creep
X = [a, b, c, d, e].
```

It seems that Prolog was using my own append predicate in the first turn, but as it enters the second level of recursion, Prolog has used its own predicate as defined in the library.

How can I override Prolog's predefined predicate (besides giving my own predicate another name)?

Comment: When I tried your example (in SWI Prolog), I didn't get the same result; it used the private `append` version. Which prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: I am also using SWI Prolog (version is 6.2.6)

Comment: I'm on version 6.0.2. Not sure if that's why the results are different. Do you have a much bigger context, or are you seeing these results just entering `swipl` and putting your code in as `[user]`?

Comment: Sorry that I can't quite get your final sentence, because I am still very new to Prolog... :(
But what I am writing is just a simple quicksort program, and I would usually just double click my file quicksort.pl, type `make.` and then `[quicksort].` in the window that popped up.

Comment: What I was suggesting, to reproduce the problem as I did, (1) enter `swipl` command, get a prolog prompt, (2) type in `[user].` followed by Enter, (3) enter just your `append` code. Then at the prolog prompt, start trace (enter `trace.`) and your example query and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion and what was the result? I see now you are "pre-compiling" the prolog and running the result.

Comment: just tried: If I use the `[user].` method to enter the code, I get the same result as yours.

Comment: I would suggest trying `foo:append(Ls,R,Result).` as your recursive call to `append/3` where `foo` is the name of the module it is defined in. See if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append/3` predicate is not a built-in predicate in SWI-Prolog but a library predicate, defined in the module `lists`. This module is likely being auto-loaded when you code is executed. There are two flags that can help here. The `autoload` flag controls auto-loading of libraries. It can be turned off the calling `set_prolog_flag(autoload, false)`. There's also another flag, `verbose_autoload`, that you can set to `true` so that auto-loading becomes verbose. Last but not least, you can use the `listing/1` predicate to examine you code. Try `listing(append/3)`. It should reveal the call to `list:append/3` in the body of clause of your predicate.

This is what I get:

```
?- set_prolog_flag(verbose_autoload, true).
true.

?- [user].
append([L|Ls],R,[L|Result]):-append(Ls,R,Result).
|: append([],X,X).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.00 sec, 3 clauses
true.

?- listing(append/3).
% autoloading user:listing/1 from /Users/pmoura/lib/swipl-7.1.8/library/listing
% autoloading system:append/3 from /Users/pmoura/lib/swipl-7.1.8/library/lists
lists:append([], A, A).
lists:append([A|B], C, [A|D]) :-
    append(B, C, D).

system:append([], A, A).
system:append([A|B], C, [A|D]) :-
    append(B, C, D).

append([A|B], C, [A|D]) :-
    append(B, C, D).
append([], A, A).

true.

?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- append([a,b,c],[d,e],X).
   Call: (6) append([a, b, c], [d, e], _G354) ? creep
   Call: (7) append([b, c], [d, e], _G436) ? creep
   Call: (8) append([c], [d, e], _G439) ? creep
   Call: (9) append([], [d, e], _G442) ? creep
   Exit: (9) append([], [d, e], [d, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) append([c], [d, e], [c, d, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) append([b, c], [d, e], [b, c, d, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) append([a, b, c], [d, e], [a, b, c, d, e]) ? creep
X = [a, b, c, d, e].

[trace]  ?-
```

Can you edit your post and tell us the exact sequence of calls that lead to the results you get?

Comment: I have edited the post with my sequence of calls. Btw when I have explicitly typed the command `set_prolog_flag(autoload, false).`, auto-loading does not occur again.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results. I do note that your `lab3` file seems to contain 10 clauses but you're only showing us the `append/3` clauses. Maybe something else in that file is causing the results you're getting?

Comment: I have just tried to delete the other codes, just leaving the 3 lines behind, but I am still getting the same result (post edited). Yet if I use the `[user]` method I won't get that problem even if I didn't explicitly called `set_prolog_flag(autoload, false).`

Comment: How do you start SWI-Prolog such that the call to `edit/0` knows which file to edit? What do you get if you call `listing(append/3)` before and after you call `make`?